# ID3 library that supports custom tags

Tags: c#, .net, mp3, id3

I'm looking for a C# library which will allow me to add custom tags to an MP3 file. I have tried taglib-sharp but can't figure out if it supports this, and how to do it. I have also tried csid3lib, UltraID3Lib and id3.net, but with no success.

Comment: Have you looked in to this library? http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Do_Anything_With_ID3.aspx

Comment: I have tried it, but no success. There are tags hard-coded into the library, but I cannot find any way to add new ones.